# ajax send request to php same value

Tags: php, ajax, request, send

I have problem in sending one variable (i) to my php.
My variable i is 6 everytime, how can i fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for (i=1; i<=5; i++){
    $('#rate'+ i +'_').click(function(){
    sendValue($(this).val(),i);
    });
}
});
function sendValue(str,str2){
$.post("/php/test.php",{ sendValue: str, sendValue2 : str2 },
    function(data){
    $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
    }, "json");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `i` as data to the handler of the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handlereventObject) event

```
for (i=1; i<=5; i++){
    $('#rate'+ i +'_').click(i, function(e){
    sendValue($(this).val(),e.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example for an explanation of what's going on.